# Is there a Tensorflow function similar to segment_min and segment_max but random?

Tags: python, tensorflow

As for segment_max and segment_min, I have both my data and my segment_ids. Instead of selecting the maximum (segment_max) or the minimum (segment_min), I would like to know if there exists a function such that returns random numbers in the data, something line segment_random.

Comment: So you want to pick random elements from contiguous subsequences in a tensor?

Answer (score 0):

That function does not exist as such, but it is not very difficult to recreate the functionality with existing operations.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def segment_random(data, segment_ids, seed=None):
    # segment_ids must be sorted 1D integer tensor
    data = tf.convert_to_tensor(data)
    segment_ids = tf.convert_to_tensor(segment_ids)
    # Find the bounds of the segments
    seg_diff = segment_ids[1:] - segment_ids[:-1]
    seg_bounds = tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.not_equal(seg_diff, 0)), 1)
    seg_bounds = tf.concat([[0], seg_bounds + 1, [tf.size(segment_ids)]], axis=0)
    # Find the size of each segment
    seg_sizes = seg_bounds[1:] - seg_bounds[:-1]
    # Pick random indices for each segment
    seg_r = tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(seg_sizes), seed=seed)
    seg_relidx = tf.cast(seg_r * tf.cast(seg_sizes, seg_r.dtype), seg_bounds.dtype)
    seg_idx = seg_relidx + seg_bounds[:-1]
    # Returned data from picked indices
    return tf.gather(data, seg_idx)

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.random.set_random_seed(0)
    out = segment_random([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                         [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4])
    print(sess.run(out))
    # [2 4 7 9]
```